# Is there a better way to find the log of any number without the C Standard Library?

Tags: c++, logging, cmath

I've to create a program that calculates the log of any number and the log of any number to any base without using `cmath`. I've succeeded in creating a prototype program using the power series equation method but I also need to create a check for the number. My tutor said that if the number is above 10 to separate the number from its largest value of 10<sup>`x`</sup> and calculate the logarithm by `log(x) + log(y)` where `x` is the number between 1 and 10 and `y` is the number 10<sup>`x`</sup>.

I've written it for numbers up to 1000 but the program using `cmath` does it to 10<sup>208</sup> and so I was wondering is there a more efficient way to calculate the log?

```
int main()
{
    float x, n;
    cin >> n;

    if (n > 10)   x = n/10;
    if (n > 100)  x = n/100;
    if (n > 1000) x = n/1000;

    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: Since it's a homework, I think you better try it on your own :-). I can only give you a hint: use a `loop`.

Comment: Haha I've been working on it for 3 weeks and i'm at the end of my tether.. i was thinking for every time you have to divide by 10 to get it into a workable number you add 1 to a count?

while (z >100)
{
x = z/10;
count++
}

log(number) = log(x) + count?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about the [Taylor's Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_series) for `log`?  It is simple to program and provides as much resolution and range as necessary.

Comment: Yes that's the series i've written and the logarithm part actually works it's the checking part which is really stumping me.

For example in class our lecturer put in 14.5e145 and the program manually separated the value from the power and calculated it. (log 14.5 + log10^145